# I want to add Figma Linear gradient to Jetpack Compose Linear Gradient

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, linear-gradients, figma, android-compose-layout, android-jetpack-compose-button

I use a Figma design to develop a android app using Jetpack Compose. I want to add a linear gradient to a button like in Figma design.

This is my Jetpack compose code. When I use this code the gradient is not same as in the Figma design.

```
val gradientBrush = Brush.linearGradient(
    colors = listOf(Color(0xFF92A3FD), Color(0xFF9DCEFF)),
    start = Offset(x = 78.75f, y = 30f),
    end = Offset(x = 236.25f, y = 30f),
)
```

This is the Figma design:

https://www.figma.com/file/s30W2cFQI6mtAe45XrE2pc/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0-1&mode=design

This is the Screen Image:

[image: Figma Design]

I want to develop the button in jetpack compose same as in the Figma design